# Is there any way to set multiple variables in one operation c#

Tags: c#

Pals, I'm new to in c# I just wonder, Is there any way to set multiple variables in one operation

My code is:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        int a = 5;
        int b = 5; 
        a += 1;
        b -= 1;

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

However I want to write them on one line like that:

```
        int a = 5;
        int b = 5; 
        a += b -= 1;

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Comment: You can set multiple variables in one expression/statement (just like you did), so what exactly is the problem you have? Please [edit] your question with a more detailed description of your problem/issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [tuple deconstruction syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#deconstruction) introduced in C# 7 to write

```
a += 1;
b -= 1;
```

in one line:

```
(a, b) = (a + 1, b - 1);
```

Note that unlike the original statements, this *will* evaluate `a` and `b` twice. This is fine if `a` and `b` are local variables, but not if `a` and `b` have side effects. I personally find the original 2 line version easier to read anyway.

`a += b -= 1` does not mean the same thing. It means:

```
int temp = b - 1;
b = temp;
a += temp;
```